# Sim800L-v2.0-network-problem

Tags: arduino-uno

I am having trouble to get Sim800L-v2.0 to work. I believe that I am supplying the necessary amount of current (5.0V, 2.1A máx power source, using solid copper wires - [circuit photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qkjs.jpg)). The Net LED keeps blinking every second, meaning that it was unable to connect to the network.

**Serial monitor readings:**

```
15:57:32.630 -> AT
15:57:32.630 -> OK

16:02:15.391 -> at+cops=? 
16:02:23.775 -> +COPS: ,(0-4),(0-2)
16:02:23.775 -> 
16:02:23.775 -> OK

16:02:29.075 ->  AT+CPIN?
16:02:29.075 -> +CME ERROR: SIM not inserted

16:02:51.008 -> AT+CREG?
16:02:51.008 -> +CREG: 0,0
16:02:51.008 -> 
16:02:51.008 -> OK

16:02:59.639 -> AT+CSQ
16:02:59.639 -> +CSQ: 0,0
16:02:59.639 -> 
16:02:59.639 -> OK

16:08:09.354 -> +CFUN: 1
16:08:09.354 -> 
16:08:09.354 -> OK
```

Inspecting the readings, it indicates that the sim card is not inserted at all, which is odd. While searching for some tips on the subject, I did encounter one or another claiming that the problem might be related to the incorrect capacitor used in the circuit module, not really sure though...

Any ideas to solve the issue? Is it a module problem, or am I missing some steps?
Thanks in advance!

[image]

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
 
//Porta do Arduino onde o pino TX do Módulo GSM esta conectado
#define TX_PIN 10
 
//Porta do Arduino onde o pino RX do Módulo GSM esta conectado
#define RX_PIN 11
 
//Cria comunicacao serial via software nas portas digitais definidas acima
SoftwareSerial serialGSM(TX_PIN, RX_PIN);
 
void setup() {
  //Begin serial comunication with Arduino and Arduino IDE (Serial Monitor)
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while(!Serial);
   
  //Inicia comunicacao serial com o GSM
  serialGSM.listen();
  serialGSM.begin(9600);
  delay(1000);
   
  Serial.println("Setup Completo!");
}
 
void loop() {
  //Le as mensagens vindas do GSM para escrevê-las no monitor serial
  if(serialGSM.available()){
    Serial.write(serialGSM.read());
  }
  
  //Le as mensagens vindas do monitor serial para copiá-las para o GSM
  if(Serial.available()){    
    serialGSM.write(Serial.read());
  }
}
```

Comment: Where are you and what network are you trying to use?

Comment: Europe, SIM card is 4g I guess, but some claim that it can switch to 2g and 3g

Comment: What network? Some networks no longer provide GSM.

Comment: I am not sure I understand, will you kindly explain? Where can I get the network you're refering to? Thanks

Comment: You should already know that information. Who did you get the SIM from? T-mobile? Vodafone? And which country specifically are you in, since the networks vary from country to country.

Comment: Ah sorry, We give it another name, that is why I got confused...I tried with Meo/Altice.Country: Portugal

Comment: Ok, that's all fine. MEO provides E-GSM (900MHz) and DCS (1800MHz) which the 800L works with. That rules that out.

Comment: Any idea why it does not work?

Comment: Not at the moment. You've exhausted my go-to answers so far...

Comment: Can you please add the code? This would make it a bit easier.

Comment: I added the code at the end of the topic, thanks.

Comment: Did you put the SIM in correctly? It will also seat on some of these boards when it is 180° off.